# discord python and mysql getting specific data

Tags: mysql, discord.py

I try to make a leveling system for discord with mysql and python but I can't find a way to see if user is in database, I search the internet but nothing works.
Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    author_id = str(ctx.author.id)

    myresult = mycursor.execute(f"select * from level where id = {author_id}")

    if myresult == author_id:
        pass
    else:
        sqladd = "INSERT INTO level (id, level, exp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        valadd = (author_id, 1, 1)
        mycursor.execute(sqladd, valadd)
        mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `myresult` to see what you're actually retrieving from the database? I also think that you need to have the select statement setup with: `mycursor.execute("select * from level where id = {author_id}")` and then `myresult = mycursor.fetchall()`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the bit to get values from the db setup as:

```
mycursor.execute(f"select * from level where id = {author_id}")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Additionally, according to how your DB schema is setup, you need to specify the position of the id on the returned tuple, since you're asking for each column's value for that entry. Since you're just checking the id, I'd recommend just changing it to `select id from level where id = {author_id}`